# Keep a method executing after throwing a exception c#

Tags: c#, exception

so I have this method that validates the format of a file. If there's something wrong with the file it throws an exception and then I catch it in the GUI and show a message to the user. 
The problem is that now I have to add a new functionality in which I show all the errors of the file. So my idea was to collect all the message from the exceptions thrown and add them to a list. But since the execution of the method stops after the first exception thrown, I cannot tell whether there are other problems with the file. 
Is there any way to keep the method running right after throwing an exception?
Thank you

Comment: Throwing an exception means *"stop everything, something is wrong."* You need to make validation failures non-exceptional. Don't throw exceptions, just collect the errors.

Comment: How about a Validation class? `if (!Validate(something)) { ExceptionList.add(something) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have some code like this....

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
    bool valid = Validate(record);

    if(!valid)
    {
        throw new Exception("Record was invalid!");
    }
}
```

Instead, you should pattern it like this:

```
var validationErrors = new List<ValidationError>();

foreach(var record in records)
{
    ValidationResult validationResult = Validate(record);

    if(!validationResult.Valid)
    {
        validationErrors.Add(validationResult.ValidationError);
        continue;
    }
}
```

This way, you're not using expensive exceptions for non-exceptional situations, and you can continue processing the rest of the valid records.

Answer (score 3):

Very simply, put your try/catch block *inside* the loop where you're reading the items.

Another option, perhaps better than relying on exceptions, might be to write a "validate()" function.